# Checkbox in kendo grid not displaying check

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I'm using kendo (2019.1.220) and knockout(v3.4.2).  I have a grid on the page with a checkbox column.  The checkbox binding is set up like this:

`<input tabindex="-1" onclick='gGridRowCheckBoxClick("308610", this.checked)' type="checkbox" data-bind="value: isChecked, checked: isChecked">`

I have a button that retrieves a new data set for the grid based on what items the user has checked.  The dataset comes back correctly with the 'isChecked' node coming back as true, but the checkbox in the grid does not display as checked.

The data looks like this on return:

```
"Data":[
    {"isChecked":true},
    {"isChecked":true},
    {"isChecked":true}
    ],
"Total":3,
"IsSuccess":true,
"Message":""}'
```

I'm not sure why the check boxes don't display as checked.

Answer (score 0):

with `<input type="checkbox" />` you only need to have the `data-bind="checked: isChecked"` added to the binding. you can remove the `value: isChecked`

Comment: I have updated my binding to be `<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked" />`
When the element returns from the server it reads: `<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: true" />`, but the box does not render a check mark still

Comment: when you say the element returns from the server, is the server returning the full element then adding it into DOM?  then that could part of the issue, as knockout will no longer recognize the binding. I haven't used KendoUI so I'm not so familiar with that side of things.

Comment: the flow is this: there is a grid on the page with one checkbox per row, the user can click on the check boxes then hit a button to show only those rows that are checked, this makes a REST call and returns data where the check boxes are evaluating to true, but not displaying checks. Hopefully that helps